# Calculate integral of product of normal distributions efficiently

Tags: algorithm, statistics, gaussian

I've got two normal PDFs, given by μ1, μ2, σ1 and σ2. What I need is the integral over the product of these functions - the solution to the problem that if X occurred at μ1 with a certain probability expressed in σ1 and Y occurred at μ2 with a certain probability, what's the probability P(X=Y)?

```
x=linspace(-500,500,1000)
e1 = normpdf(x,mu1,sigma1)
e2 = normpdf(x,mu2,sigma2)
solution = sum(e1*e2)
```

To visualise, e1 is blue, e2 green, and `e1*e2` is red (magnified by factor 100 for visualisation):

[image: Product of two PDFs]

Is there however a more direct way of computing `solution` given `mu1`, `mu2`, `sigma1` and `sigma2`?

Thanks!

Comment: i think that question would fit much better at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be solved analytically or at least approximated, so this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions . You need assumptions about the **joint distribution** of x and y. Knowing only the pdfs is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the integral easily enough, but it does not mean what you think it means.

A mathematical normal distribution yields a randomly chosen real, which you could think of as containing an infinite number of random digits after the decimal point. The chance of any two numbers from such distributions being the same (even if they are from the same distribution) is zero.

A continuous probability density function p(x) like the normal distribution does not give, at p(x), the probability of the random number being x. Roughly speaking, it says that if you have a small interval of width delta-x at x then the probability of a random number being inside that interval is delta-x times p(x). For exact equality, you have to set delta-x to zero, so again you come out with probability zero.

To compute the interval (whatever it means) you might note that N(x;u,o) = exp(-(x-u)^2)/2o^2) neglecting terms that I can't be bothered to look up in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution, and if you multiply two of these together you can add the stuff inside the exp(). If you do enough algebra you might end up with something that you can rewrite as another exponential with a quadratic inside, which will turn into another normal distribution, up to some factors which you can pull outside the integral sign.

A better way of approaching something like this problem would be to note that the difference of two normal distributions with mean M1 and M2 and variance V1 and V2 is a normal distribution with mean M1 - M2 and variance V1 + V2. Perhaps you could consider this distribution - you can easily work out that the probability that the difference of your two numbers is within any range that catches your fancy, for example between -0.0001 and +0.0001.